# Unable to make an MQTT pub-sub connection

Tags: mqtt, eclipse-hono, bosch-iot-suite, bosch-iot

I have been trying to make a simple MQTT pub sub communication on my device using node-red.
I have published and subscribed to the topic: telemetry. the server and port used are : mqtt.bosch-iot-hub.com:8883 .
For the TLS configuration, the iot hub certificate provided by bosch is being used(https://docs.bosch-iot-hub.com/cert/iothub.crt).
I am able to successfully publish the data on the topic and receive it using a HONO receiver. But when I directly subscribe to that topic using node-red mqtt-in node or mosquitto_sub, it doesn't receive the data.

Can someone please help me understand why is it happening and what could be the possible solution to it?

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to achieve by subscribing to the "telemetry" topic?

Comment: I just wanted to send and receive telemetry data using Bosch Iot Suite using an API. But because i dont have it ready right now that is why i am using node-red. Also I dont have a particular use case in mind. I am exploring the IoT Suite right now so as to understand its working and then work on some use case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in devices subscribing to the `telemetry` topic. In Hono (and thus the Bosch IoT Hub) devices only *publish* telemetry data and/or events. Such data is consumed by downstream applications using Hono's north bound, AMQP 1.0 based [Telemetry](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/api/telemetry/#northbound-operations) and [Event](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/api/event/#northbound-operations) APIs. Applications can use Hono's AMQP 1.0 based [Command & Control API](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/api/command-and-control/) to send commands to (connected) devices. In order to receive commands, MQTT based devices need to [subscribe to the `command` topic](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/user-guide/mqtt-adapter/#command-control).